# Open, Write and Read ttyUSB0

Tags: c++, c

I am doing a program to open, write and read the port ttyUSB0, I have the next program and I don´t write anything. Can anyone help me please????

My question is that I have a problem with the write or read function, because I can´t read and write in the ttyUSB0 port, and I search a solution to write and read ttyUSB0 port.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;

int serial_open(char *serial_name, speed_t baud)
{
      struct termios newtermios;
      int fd;
      fd = open(serial_name,O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
      newtermios.c_cflag= CBAUD | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
      newtermios.c_iflag=IGNPAR;
      newtermios.c_oflag=0;
      newtermios.c_lflag=0;
      newtermios.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
      newtermios.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
      cfsetospeed(&newtermios,baud);
      cfsetispeed(&newtermios,baud);
      if (tcflush(fd,TCIFLUSH)==-1) return -1;
      if (tcflush(fd,TCOFLUSH)==-1) return -1;
      if (tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtermios)==-1) return -1;
      return fd;
}    
void serial_send(int serial_fd, char *data, int size)
{
  write(serial_fd, data, size);
}

int serial_read(int serial_fd, char *data, int size, int timeout_usec)
{
      fd_set fds;
      struct timeval timeout;
      int count=0;
      int ret;
      int n;
      do {
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET (serial_fd, &fds);
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = timeout_usec;
        ret=select (FD_SETSIZE,&fds, NULL, NULL,&timeout);
        if (ret==1) {
          n=read (serial_fd, &data[count], size-count);
          count+=n;
          data[count]=0;
   }
 } while (count<size && ret==1);
 return count;
}

void serial_close(int fd)
{
   close(fd);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int serial_fd, n, longitud,;
   char *device=”at”;
   char *data;
   longitud=strlen(device);

   serial_fd = serial_open("/dev/ttyUSB0",B38400);
    if (serial_fd == -1) {
            printf ("Error opening the serial device: %s\n",argv[1]);
            perror("OPEN");
            exit(0);
    }
    printf("SERIAL OPEN:%s\n", device);
    serial_send(serial_fd, device, longitud);
    printf ("String sent------> %s\n",device);
    n=serial_read(serial_fd,data,longitud,10000);
    printf("Se ha recibido %s \n Tamaño: %d\n n:%d \n serial_fd:%d\n",data, longitud,n,serial_fd);
puts(data);
    serial_close(serial_fd);
//    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do the [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or [`write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) system calls return with an error code? Have you checked what the error is? Always check for errors, and *what* the error is (done by checking [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), print error using either [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) or get a string using [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html)).

Comment: With Open I return a '3', with write I don´t return anything and with read I return a '0', this '0' is that I don't receive anything

Comment: When `read` returns zero it means the "connection" have been closed, or that the "end-of-file" has been reached. And you really need to check what `write` returns. And all other system calls as well (and *do* remember to check `errno` when a system calls returns with a failure (e.g. `-1`)).

Comment: I do this     `int n;`
  `n=write(serial_fd, &data, size);` and write return '2'

Comment: Well are you *really* passing `&data` as the second argument? That's not what the code in the question show, and it will be passing a pointer to the pointer (which will be pointing to the completely wrong memory) and give you undefined behavior. And again I ask, *what* is `write` returning and *what* is `errno` if there's an error? And do any of the *other* system call fail (both the one you check and the ones you don't check)?

Comment: in write I do this   `write(serial_fd, data, size);`
 ` perror("WRITE");` and I receive SUCCESS and in read it return SUCCESS

Comment: First of all, only check `errno` if a function actually fails, otherwise the value of `errno` is undefined. Secondly, it seems the functions to read and write *do* read and write successfully. So the problem is maybe not on your end in this program?

Comment: I send 'at' by ttyUSB0, and when I send this I have to receive a 'OK', and I receive 1�I��^H��H���PTI���@

Comment: It is possible that the ttyUSB0 has a bad configuration???? How can I know it???

Comment: When you send to modem a command let's say AT or ATI you must append to your command carriage return and new line characters (0xd0xa), so your "AT" command becomes "AT\r\n" and "ATI\r\n". Imagine that example, your modem accept thought USB a serial sequence, modem accept this char sequence also accept special chars like backspace (what delete last character arrived), now question is when to execute command if you don't tell him to execute, ending successfully command sequence must be ending with "\r\n".

Comment: If you use linux open a terminal and dump hex data from USB (/dev/ttyUSB0) using "hexdump -C /dev/ttyUSB0" then open second terminal to send to this file using "echo -e "ATI\r\n" > /dev/ttyUSB0". After you do that you will see any hex value for each character and on the right ASCII printable character and ? for non printable char format, you will observe easy after each received command from the modem 0xd0xaOK0xd0xa pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program works just fine with the writing and reading, but you have another problem: [*Undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You have a pointer variable in your `main` function named `data`, and you pass this to your `serial_read` function. But nowhere do you make this pointer actually point anywhere, so when that pointer is dereferenced you have the undefined behavior.

Local (non-static) variables are not initialized, their value is indeterminate. You need to initialize the variable, to make it actually point somewhere. I recommend you make it into an array instead.

And then when you call `serial_read` you only ask to read two bytes (the length of the string `"at"`), instead of the actual size of the data (which currently is none), you need to pass the actual size of the buffer instead.

So to sum it up:

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
    char data[256];
    ...
    n = serial_read(serial_fd, data, sizeof(data), 10000);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do this I don´t receive anything, I use Docklight to see if the port work ok and in Docklight I send 'at<CR><LF>' and I receive a '0', that it is ok

Comment: @Igor Shouldn't your code also send the `<CR><LF>` characters then ? It seems your code only sends "at" ?